# format string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format strings that displayed in a table, i.e. AbcDeF with different font size for each character. Each string in different row will have different pattern, that is decided by a vector passed with the string in Json format, i.e. ['abcde',[1,2]] indicates letter "b" and "c" in string "abcde" will be in different font size/color in the final display.  This means that each pattern of a string are dynamically assigned.

I have modified original code based on tenbits' answer, and all works well except all the strings only formatted by the last string format vector, code with results on fiddle,

https://fiddle.jshell.net/wrwhxdd4/7/

By carefully reading the document of .each() function, I found the problem is that the setter function, i.e. .css() acts over the entire collection of matched elements, in this case all strings in column 1 and formatted with the pattern designated for the last row. I cannot find a solution to work callback function on each row individually using the the specific pattern assigned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what you have and we can help you.

Comment: To be clear, jQuery *is* javascript.

Comment: You can still use javascript when using jQuery.

Comment: To clarify further, jQuery isn't JavaScript. jQuery is a JavaScript library, which is like being able to use shortcuts in JavaScript. :)

Comment: @clomp, picky, picky! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrapp each letter with some html tag:

```js
var json_data = [['hello', [1,4]], ['Hello', [0,3]], ['HELLO', [2,3]]];

generateTable(json_data);

function generateTable(arr){
    $('#my-table').html('<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><tr>');
    $.each(arr, function(index, val) {
        var str = val[0];
        var pattern = val[1];
        var html = colorizeLetters(str, pattern);
        var $row = $('<tr>');
        var $cell1 = $('<td class="1">').html(html);
        var $cell2 = $('<td>').html(pattern.join(', '));

        $row.append($cell1).append($cell2).appendTo('#my-table');
    });
}

function randomColor(){
    return "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
}

function colorizeLetters(text, indexes) {
    return text.split('').reduce(function(html, letter, i){
        if (indexes != null && indexes.indexOf(i) === -1)
            return html + letter;

        var c = '<font color="' + randomColor() + '">' + letter + "</font>";
        return html + c;
    }, "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='my-table'></table>
```

*EDIT:*
The problem in your code [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/wrwhxdd4/7/) is the line with `$('#display_1 td.1').each` - it always references all `td`. That mean, on 3rd iteration of `$.each(json_data` it references also previous 2 rows, as they all have the class `.1`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am thinking it maybe a dumb question:).

Comment: I cannot apply this function on dynamic data, I am still beginner in JQuery:). Thanks!

Comment: You should put that code **after** the generated table, otherwise there are no "#display_1 td" elements in the document. _Please give a short feedback about this_

Comment: Is there any way to apply callback function on each row of a column instead of acting over all elements in that column at the same time?

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean? Also see my edit, I have refactored a little, so that on each cell we call a function to get the html of colorized text.

Comment: Even with the refactoring I got the same results. The problem is that I cannot format each cell with the extra parameter passed with the specific string, i.e. an index vector indicating which letter should change color, and the whole column was formatted by the same vector.  The code can be found in fiddle link provided above.

Comment: @bmi1213, Ok I got it know, you want to colorize only specific letters. See my edits now.

Comment: many thanks, this is exactly what I want.  In var $cell1 = $('<td class="1">').html(html); is it not necessary to have a subclass 1 since html has already individually formatted?

Comment: @bmi1213, you are welcome. Yes, the class `1` is not required. It just there due to copy paste of your code)